# Django auto generate identifier number

Tags: python, django

I want to define the unique identifier field for the Django user model.
I want the numbers like 0000-0000-0001,  0000-0000-0002 when save the models.

Approach:
I can define field as char and post_save signal can update the identifier based on primary key.

Is there any automatic way to generate number like this for the user identifier (not primary key)

Comment: Futile effort, waste of time and energy. Use string formatting to display it like this when you display the numbers.

Comment: Should they be successive? If not you can use `uuid` module

Comment: @e4c5 got it right. Just format the `user.id` this way and you're done.

Comment: @e4c5 Good point, not so good tone!

Comment: the uuid generates very long random number. I want at least 10-12 digits long (uuid uniqueness is not 100% sure)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Until someone has cleverer solution for the *dash-separated zero-padding* formatting you can display the user's primary key like this:

```py
_id = "{:0>9d}".format(user.pk)
identifier = "{}-{}-{}".format(_id[0:3], _id[3:6], _id[6:])
```